# Open hangout link from desktop

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-hangouts

i would like to implement a parmanent hangout room (creating a repeated day event on google calendar)where some user (only invited people to that calendar event) in different places/room can join that hangout at any time. I can create a shortcut from chrome in the dekstop (whose link is aplayws the same) but the problem is how i can handle session/cookie authetication so stat a user does not have periodically to re-enter username and password? I want that users don't know username and password and just log in to the hangout from the desktop shortcut. How i can implement this?Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Google has a lot of security measures to prevent automated means of creating sessions. It's recommended that users sign into their own Google accounts manually.